# Unable to update MySql database C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update the database from different types of controls, which are populated when the element is selected in Gridview, but my code is not working and I don't know what else to do. Thank you in advance for your help.
Below is my code:

Main method to update the database:

```
public static void Editez_Nota(int idintrare, int idspecializare, int idnivelstudii, int idanstudiu, int idstudent, int idmaterie, int idprof, double iddnota, DateTime dataEvaluarii)
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand editezNota = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog SET iddspec=@iddspec, iddnivel=@iddnivel, " +
            "iddan=@iddan, iddstudent=@iddstudent, iddmaterie=@iddmaterie, iddprof=@iddprof, " +
            "iddnota=@iddnota, idddata=CAST(@idddata as datetime) WHERE idintrare=@idintrare", conn);
        try
        {

            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idintrare", idintrare); **//this was missing**
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddspec", idspecializare);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddnivel", idnivelstudii);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddan", idanstudiu);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddstudent", idstudent);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddmaterie", idmaterie);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddprof", idprof);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddnota", iddnota);
            editezNota.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idddata", dataEvaluarii);
            editezNota.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Save button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int rowindex = dataGridViewNote.CurrentRow.Index;
            int id_intrare = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewNote.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            int idspecializare = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxSpec.SelectedValue);
            int idnivelstudii = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxNivel.SelectedValue);
            int idanstudiu = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxAn.SelectedValue);
            int idstudent = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxStudent.SelectedValue);
            int idmaterie = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxMaterie.SelectedValue);
            int idprof = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxProf.SelectedValue);
            double iddnota = Convert.ToDouble(textNota.Text);


            DB_Catalog.Editez_Nota(id_intrare, idspecializare, idnivelstudii, idanstudiu, idstudent, idmaterie, idprof, iddnota, dateTimeevaluare.Value.Date);
            dataGridViewNote.DataSource = DB_Catalog.Populez_Note();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: How do you know your code is not working? What would you expect your code to do, and how do you know this isn't taking place?

Comment: When I select a row from the table, the controls get populated and I can make changes. However, when I press the button to save the changes, I receive the following error: "Fatal error encountered during command execution".

Comment: My understanding is this error is raised when there is something wrong in the MySQL syntax. What happens when you run the query using some client program, such as the [MySQL command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), Server Explorer in Visual Studio, or HeidiSQL (anything in [this list](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-MySQL-client-for-Mac-OS-X-or-Windows))?

Comment: I ran the query in phpmyadmin and it works fine, the table is getting updated

Comment: Could you post the query as you ran it in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. The problem was with the fact that it could not identify the primary key of the table (WHERE  clause), because I did not declare the variable that stores the primary key of the selected item in the datagrid. 
I will edit the code, in case somebody else makes the same silly mistake
Thank you all for your answers!